# Getting reference to Vue 3 Template Refs in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `v-for` with text input components.  The number of text input components is unknown and variable.  Each text input component can emit an `@update` event.  When one of these input components emits this `@update` event I need to be call an exposed method on the input component.

Here's some sample code:

```
const textInputs = ref([])

function callComponentMethod() {
 // Call an exposed method on the TextInput that called this function
}
```

```
<TextInput v-for="(section, index) in sections" ref="textInputs" @update="callComponentMethod" />
```

I thought I might be able to pass the `index` to the `callComponentMethod` function and use that to reference the correct textInput ref, but the Vue 3 docs state that "the ref array does not guarantee the same order as the source array", so I don't think that's a viable solution.

How can I reference the correct TextInput within the `callComponentMethod` function?  Is there a way to pass a self reference to it?  Like `@update="callComponentMethod($self)"` or something?

I've researched for answers but I can't find any solution that will work when the # of components within the v-for is variable.

Update:
I considered doing it like this:

```
<TextInput v-for="(section, index) in sections" ref="textInputs" @update="callComponentMethod(index)" />
```

```
function callComponentMethod(index: number) {
 // Call an exposed method on the TextInput that called this function
  textInputs.value[index].myCustomMethod()
}
```

But the problem is what the Vue 3 docs state that "the ref array does not guarantee the same order as the source array" so I can't be sure that the indexed Ref I'm accessing is the same one that called the method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you wanted to implement multiple inputs at the same time and wanted to get them separately in `callComponentMethod` based on user input.

There are few ways to do this, but I recommend that you pass index as a prop in `TextInput` and pass it back with inputted text when you emit `update` like this:

```js
<TextInput v-for="(section, index) in sections" ref="textInputs" @update="callComponentMethod" :index="index" />
```

and in the component,

```
const data = { index: props.index, search: "text" }
this.$emit("update", data)
```

and receive them here

```
function callComponentMethod(data) {
 // Call an exposed method on the TextInput that called this function
}
```

Comment: I considered doing it like this:

`<TextInput v-for="(section, index) in sections" ref="textInputs" @update="callComponentMethod(index)" />`

`function callComponentMethod(index: number) {
 // Call an exposed method on the TextInput that called this function
  textInputs.value[index].myCustomMethod()
}`

Comment: I think this is essentially what you're telling me to do, just simplified a bit.  The problem is what was stated within Vue 3's documentation:  "the ref array does not guarantee the same order as the source array".  If that's true, then I can't guarantee that I'm accessing the correct ref based on the index.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?